# Finding character location of all instances of a string in bash

Tags: string, bash, awk

I'm trying to find the location of all instances of a string in a particular file; however, the code I'm currently running only returns the location of the first instance and then stops there. Here is what I'm currently running:

```
str=$(cat temp1.txt) 
tmp="${str%%<C>*}"

if [ "$tmp" != "$str" ]; then
echo ${#tmp}
fi
```

The file is only one line of string and I would display it but the format questions need to be in won't allow me to add the proper amount of spaces between each character.

Comment: Sample input and expected output, please.

Comment: I tried to submit the sample input, but the formatting of the question doesn't allow me to apply the right amount of spacing between characters. It essentially is one line containing <C> multiple times with various amounts of spaces between each. I just need the location of each occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of many details of your requirements, however this is an `awk` one-liner:

```
awk -vRS='<C>' '{printf("%u:",a+=length($0));a+=length(RS)}END{print ""}' temp1.txt
```

Let’s test it with an actual line of input:

```
$ awk -vRS='<C>' \
  '{printf("%u:",a+=length($0));a+=length(RS)}END{print ""}' \
   <<<"    <C>       <C>  "
4:14:20:
```

This means: the first `<C>` is at byte 4, the second `<C>` is at byte 14 (including the three bytes of the first `<C>`), and the whole line is 20 bytes long (including final newline).

Is this what you want?

***Explanation***

We set (`-v`) record separator (`RS`) as `<C>`. Then we keep a variable `a` with the count of all bytes processed so far. For each “line” (i.e., `<C>`-separated substrings) we add the length of the current line to `a`, `printf` it with a suitable format `"%u:"`, and increase `a` by the length of the separator which ended the current line. Since no printing so far included newlines, at the `END` we `print` an empty string, which is an idiom to output a final newline.

Comment: I ran this and my computer seems to be rejecting the -v record separator: "awk: invalid -v option"

Comment: Disregard, there was a typo and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the basically the same question asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153339/how-to-find-a-position-of-a-character-using-grep).

In particular your question may be answered for multiple instances  thanks to user 
[JRFerguson](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22999/jrferguson) response using perl.

EDIT:  I found another solution that might just do the trick [here](http://www.unix.com/302949631-post4.html). (The main question and response post is found [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/259372-how-get-index-values-multiple-matches-same-line-awk.html).)

I changed the shell from ksh to bash, changed the searched string to include multiple `<C>`'s to better demonstrate an answer the question, and named it  "tester":

```
 #!/bin/bash
printf '%s\n' '<C>abc<C>xyz<C>123456<C>zzz<C>' | awk -v s="$1" '
{       d = ""
        for(i = 1; x = index(substr($0, i), s); i = i + x + length(s) - 1) {
                printf("%s%d", d, i + x - 1)
                d = ":"
        }
        print ""
}'
```

This is how I ran it:

```
$ tester '<C>'
1:7:13:22:28
```

I haven't figured the code out (I like to know why it works) but it seems to work! It would nice to get an explanation and an elegant way to feed your string into this script. Cheers.

Comment: I actually used this question to write my first attempt at this code. It only returns the first occurrence of the string I'm searching for.